Monte-Carlo metropolis algorithm for Ising model
I am using the Monte-Carlo metropolis algorithm to simulate the Ising model. Since the convergence is slow near $T_c$, I am looking for a method to speed up the problem. What I did was instead of evaluating the algorithm one site at a time, I am doing it for all sites simultaneously in each iteration. Is this a valid method?
EDIT: What I observe is that the the algorithm converges to the half-full lattice (density = 0.5) at temperatures above $T_c$. Some figures are drawn below:


As we can see, there is a horizontal line that we do not expect. What is causing it?

This is a valid perturbation of the state in the MCMC framework, but it is possible that you get very low acceptance rates. What do you observe?

I presume you have looked at the various cluster algorithms?  E.g. in https://csml.northwestern.edu/resources/Reprints/lnp_color.pdf


Is this a valid method?

No, it is not.
MC cannot be fully parallelized.
If you want to partially parallelize, there are several papers on it.

The OP doesn't mention parallelism. Why do you think the question is about parallelism?

@IanBush, I am doing it for all sites simultaneously in each iteration. --- he is trying to achieve speedup using parallelism. I am working on parallelism myself. So, I think, that was his intention, too.

I think what they mean is that they are attempting to flip the spins (or equivalent) on many or all  of the sites in a given iteration, rather than just on one. This is a perfectly valid variation on the algorithm but, as noted in the comment to the question, can lead to very low acceptance rates.
